# How to show different images according to selectInput in Shiny?

Tags: r, image, shiny

I have an app that shows population models with a dropdown menu to choose the species. A plot of that species' model will be rendered and now I want an image of the species next to that plot. 
The plot will change when the dates or location is changed, but the image next to it should only react to the select species input.

I've written this code for it:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
 # ... rest of the code
  wellPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(3, selectInput("populatie", label = h4("Populatie"), 
                        choices = list("PERENBLADVLO" = "PER", "OORWORM" = "OOR", "FLUWEELMIJT" = "FLU"),
                        selected = "PER"),
             imageOutput("img1")), # here is the image
      column(9, plotOutput("plot2"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
 # ... rest of the code
  output$img1 <- renderImage({
    if(input$populatie == "PER"){            
      img(height = 240, width = 300, src = "PBV.jpg")
    }                                        
    else if(input$populatie == "OOR"){
      img(height = 240, width = 300, src = "OW.jpg")
    }
    else if(input$populatie == "FLU"){
      img(height = 240, width = 300, src = "FM.jpg")
    }
  })
 # ... rest of the code
}
```

What I get is an error saying "invalid filename argument". 
I can render the images on their own though without a selection.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't quite understand why it's like this, but I found a solution:

It works fine when I use `uiOutput()` and `renderUI({})` instead of `imageOutput` and `renderImage({})`.
The rest of the code is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is so long ago, but here's the reason in case someone else is looking at this later:

You would use `ImageOutput()` and `renderImage()` if you could read in your images in the ui function because they don't depend on user input.. otherwise (most of the time) if you're reading in the images in your server function and the image you read depends on user input you'd use `uiOutput()` and `renderUI()`

hope this makes sense!